# Is a particular AWS Lambda function launched in the same machine always?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

We have created an AWS Lambda function in Python through the console, and tested by clicking the "Test" button. It works fine.

So now I'd like to understand, every time when I hit "Test",

- Does this Lambda function always run on the same machine?
- Does AWS Lambda launch the container on the same machine in which user function will be executed?

If not, what if I create a sub-process within the handler function, how to get hold of the running sub-process between multiple invocations of this Lambda function?

Appreciate for the clarification!

Comment: You can't. It will be terminated as soon as your function finishes. You can only sometimes reuse context, e.g. what is in /tmp folder or some global variables.

Comment: Thanks Marcin! actually I am trying to implement a long running asynchronous process which should be up & running all the time, basically I have a code that implements producer-consumer pattern, so I want this process to be up & running for longer period using lambda, is lambda ideal solution for this use-case?

Comment: Even if I create a daemon process within lambda function which runs in background asynchronously, will it still be terminated when the handler function exits out,

Comment: yes. it would be a huge loop hole that ppl would exploit to get their processes run more than 15 minutes. If you need something that runs >15 min, then lambda by itself is probably not a good solution for your problem.

Comment: @Manoranjan your use case is not compatible with AWS Lambda at all. I would suggest using AWS ECS with Fargate.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! @Marcin!

Answer (score 2):

An AWS Lambda function has a **chance** that it will rerun the same container on the same machine, it can even restart a process that was running in the container when Lambda stopped running the container. The important thing to remember when designing your Lambda function is that this is **not** guaranteed. You have to write your Lambda function so that it can handle subsequent executions being done on a clean environment on a different machine.

Please remember that AWS Lambda Functions will be stopped after 15 minutes of run time. Please see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

You could try designing your Lambda so that it does some processing, then stores the data elsewhere, then the next Lambda function that launches will perform some more processing as soon as the previous Lambda finishes. You usually want to use Lambda for workloads that wait for a certain event or time before performing more processing.

One of the best use cases for using Lambda is only paying for processing power when you need it.

For your use case you might want to consider using some other container service like:

EKS - https://aws.amazon.com/eks/
or
ECS - https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/

Or possibly even consider Elastic Beanstalk - https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: Your assertion that there is "NO carry over from the last Lambda that ran" is not true. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/